# ISPConfig 3 One click cms install when creating website

Tags: nginx, deployment, debian, ispconfig

I would like to know if it's possible to create an script that allow me or the client to install a cms in one click (like wordpress) via ISPConfig admin panel.

What i would like to do is this:

- Create bdd & user
- Download last and/or specific version of a CMS
- Install CMS with specific informations (bdd & client info)
- Give these files the right owner on the ftp

For the most part i think that i'm capable of doing it but i don't know how to implement it on ISPConfig or even if it's possible.

Thank's for reading :D